# Scrape does not return the expected value

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I am using a ruby script and Nokogiri to scrap a webpage.

In this code I want to retrieve the matchs time: (that's for a slakbot, it says if match has started and what are the live score, and it tells at what time matchs start).

*The url I scrap:*

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://fr.fifa.com/worldcup"))
```

my method:

```
match_times = doc.css('.fi-mu__m').map {|time| time.css('.fi-mu__score-info').css('.fi-mu__match-time').css('.fi-s__scoreText').map(&:text)}.flatten.map{|time| time.gsub( / *\n+/, "" ).gsub( / *\r+/, "" ).lstrip.rstrip }.map {|time| (Time.parse(time) - 3600).strftime("%H:%M")}
```

my result:

```
["14:00", "17:00", "19:00", "11:45", "11:45", "11:45", "11:45"]
```

I need the 3 first results... 
**"14:00", "17:00"** are right but **"19:00"** is not good... it should be **"20:00"**

Here is what the DOM display:

While I am writing this question, the first match has started so I don't need it for now...

For the second match:

```
<div class="fi-mu__match-time" data-timeutc="15:00" data-timeshiftutc="180" data-daymonthutc="2206" data-timelocal="18:00" data-mytime="17:00">
          <span class="fi-s__scoreText">17:00</span>
        </div>
```

For the third match:

```
<div class="fi-mu__match-time" data-timeutc="18:00" data-timeshiftutc="120" data-daymonthutc="2206" data-timelocal="20:00" data-mytime="20:00">
          <span class="fi-s__scoreText">20:00</span>
        </div>
```

I don't know what is wrong... I need to get `data-mytime`value...

Comment: Seems like a time zone issue. Why not grab the utc times? You can handle the offset from there? Also as a sidenote the word is "scrape" not "scrap"

Comment: Offset are different according where are the matchs... I don't know how to manage this :( (thanks for the side note ;) )

Comment: The UTC time will not change the "time of the match" will change based on where the person watching it is located e.g. it is currently 13:16 UTC but in my timezone it is 09:16

Comment: Okay but how do I grab the utc times?

Comment: `data-timeutc="18:00"` `data-timeutc="15:00"`

Comment: my question is how to scrap this ? what is the syntax please? I know with css.... but how to do this with the data-timeutc

Comment: `doc.css('.fi-mu__match-time').map {|t| t.attributes["data-timeutc"].value}`

Comment: I think you are getting the information from a source where there is a mistake in the time (the first two have one hour difference and the third two hours).  To get the time in `utc` you just need to do `Time.parse(time).utc`.  If you add 3600 you will get it in CET, but the 3rd item is incorrect.  You need to put +7200 for that so just compensate for that.